# how to Salesforce integration with website in C#

Tags: c#, salesforce

I have created one .net Web application to fetch some data and metadata from Salesforce. So, this application first ask for the salesforce username and password to login and once log-in is successful, it will fetch some data from salesforce.

i am trying below code it is right way or wrong, please suggest proper way

```
    string response_type = "code";
    string client_id = "...";
    string redirect_url = @"...";
    string client_secret = "....";

    // GET: LoginApp

    public void Login()
    {
         authorize();
    }


    public void authorize()
    {
        Redirect("");

        string URI = "";

        StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
        body.Append(URI);
        body.Append("?response_type=" + response_type + "&");
        body.Append("client_id=" + client_id + "&");
        body.Append("client_secret=" + client_secret + "&");
        body.Append("redirect_uri=" + redirect_url);
        //string red_url = body.ToString();
        string red_url = HttpPost(body.ToString());
        Response.Redirect(URI);
    }


    public string HttpPost(string URI)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(URI);
        request.Method = "POST";
        string postData = "This is a test data.";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        string res = request.RequestUri.ToString();
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: how we can implement in website with login authentication

Comment: Are you asking how to implement login and authentication? Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes. salesforce integration with web application in new for me. i have already trying some peace of code but not understanding fully.  help me for this.

Comment: This is not how SO works - it is not a coding service. Post specific issues regarding errors or where you are stuck, along with your code, and people will try to help.

Comment: can anyone update me.